# Equivalent to Kappa or MCC that compares to baseline classifier?

Tags: classification, model-evaluation, unbalanced-classes

Both Cohen's Kappa ($\kappa$) and Matthew's Correlation Coefficient (MCC) measure the improvement of a classifier compared to a random classifier. This means that, for a classifier with a confusion matrix
$$      \begin{array}{c|ccc|c}
        & &predicted & \\ 
        true & \omega_1 & \ldots & \omega_K & \sum_i C_{ij} \\\hline
        \omega_1 & C_{11} & \cdots & C_{1K} & n_1 \\
        \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots \\
        \omega_K & C_{K1} & \cdots & C_{KK} & n_K \\\hline
        \sum_j C_{ij} & k_1 & \ldots & k_K & \sum_i n_i=N
      \end{array}$$
they measure $A-p_C$ where $A=\sum_i C_{ii}/N$ is the *accuracy* and $p_C$ is the accuracy of a random classification with probabilities *equal to the frequencies in the conusion matrix*, that is:
$$p_C = \sum_i \frac{k_i}{N}\cdot\frac{n_i}{N}$$

Both $\kappa$ and MCC are normalized versions of the difference $A-p_C$ and differ in the normalization factor ($\kappa$ can even become negative). Both do not compare, however, with a baseline classifier always voting for the most frequent class, but with a poorer classifier instead based on the decisions of the classifier that is to be evaluated. This leads to my questions:

1. Is there an established performance measure that compares with a baseline classifier (similar to $R^2$ in regression problems)?
2. How should it be normalized?